# Use Bing Search API in Windows Azure Marketplace get latest news according to date using news service operation and NewsSortBy with c sharp code

Tags: c#, bing

I need a way to use kby Date with bing search API in Windows Azure Marketplace to get latest news (last 24 hrs for example) in c sharp code, or any other way to control the news retrieved by news service operation to be uptodated (only latest news during the day).

Comment: Does `kby Date` stands for `query by date`?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the [Bing API v2 reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd251056.aspx).
And here is the code samples of [how to retrieve News](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd251089.aspx).
Note that code samples are written on JS, but they look pretty clearly and could be easily converted to c#.

**p.s.** I didn't explicit piece of code doing like `get the news for last 24 hrs`, however there is such nice thing:

```
for (var i = 0; i < results.length; ++i)
{     
            // omitted to make answer shorted

            resultStr = "<a href=\""
                + results[i].Date   // <--               
            // omitted to make answer shorted

}
```

**UPDATE: How to get only news for last 24 hrs**

I see the solution for getting news for last 24 hr's in the following way:

Let's define `stale news item` as news with days out of 24 hr frame, and let 'fresh' is the opposite.

1. Get the top N news items(let's say initial value for N is 50).
2. If results do not contain stale news item - then retrieve *next*(*) N news items and repeat this until stale is appeared in results.
3. Ignore stale ones. Assing N = count of fresh news items.
4. Repeat steps 2-3 each next time in order to have news up to date.

**Disclaimer** Please note that the algorithm is very far from optimal in terms of performance, it's supposed only to demonstrate the main idea.

`*` How to load *next N news items*. Should be achiveable by loading data as pages via "$top"  and "$skip" query options. In [Quick Start Guide](https://skydrive.live.com/view.aspx?resid=9C9479871FBFA822!112&app=Word&authkey=!ANNnJQREB0kDC04) is the sample how get news('Executing a news Service Operion' section).

```
// This is the query expression.    
string query = "Xbox Live Games";

// Create a Bing container.    
string rootUrl = "https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search";

var bingContainer = new Bing.BingSearchContainer(new Uri(rootUrl));

// The market to use.    
string market = "en-us";

// Get news for science and technology.    
string newsCat = "rt_ScienceAndTechnology";

// Configure bingContainer to use your credentials.    
bingContainer.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(AccountKey, AccountKey);

// Build the query, limiting to 10 results.    
var newsQuery =

bingContainer.News(query, null, market, null, null, null, null, newsCat, null);

newsQuery = newsQuery.AddQueryOption("$top", 10);

// Run the query and display the results.

var newsResults = newsQuery.Execute();

foreach (var result in newsResults)

{

Console.WriteLine("{0}-{1}\n\t{2}",

result.Source, result.Title, result.Description);

}
```

Pay attention to line `newsQuery = newsQuery.AddQueryOption("$top", 10);`. It should be possible(not sure if it is) to specify `"$skip"` options, which makes you capable of using the paging functionality.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This code is available in the following link: https://skydrive.live.com/view.aspx?resid=9C9479871FBFA822!112&app=Word&authkey=!ANNnJQREB0kDC04

Comment: My problem is how to use newssortby with date which is also find in the above link in order to get latest news. Any idea/ thanks for your support

Comment: Sorry, can't access the link above - I'm behind corporate firewall at the moment. Does this piece of code `"&News.SortBy=Relevance"` grabbed from [yet another one sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd251010.aspx) give you any hint?

Comment: The Bing Search API 2.0 is transitioning to an offering that's available in Windows Azure Marketplace via subscription so it not working anymore, i need something similar to that but for windows azure market place